# como crear rama develop en un proyecto que ya esta avanzado y solo tiene rama master

Tags: git-flow

tengo un repositorio en bitbucket de un proyecto angular el problema es que cuando se creo el proyecto no se creo la rama develop entonces el proyecto únicamente cuenta con la rama master y todos los cambios se hacen directamente a esa rama, mi pregunta es ¿como puedo crear la rama develop mediante git flow?

Comment: ¿Revisaste [los tutoriales en el propio sitio de Bitbucket](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)?

Comment: si, pero tengo duda, ya que el proyecto esta en producción y no quiero romper el sitio web ya que soy novato en esos temas quería la opinión de gente con un poco mas de experiencia en ese tema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo la metodología git-flow la rama develop sale de master:

[image: Git flow]

Por lo que lo primero, si no lo estás ya, deberías hacer checkout a la rama master:

```
git checkout master
```

Si tus cambios no están sincronizados, haz un pull para que tu rama local esté al mismo nivel que la rama remota:

```
git pull
```

En este estado solo tienes que crear la rama develop en local y hacer push para que se cree también la rama remota:

```
git checkout -b develop
git push origin develop
```

Las demás personas que trabajen en ese proyecto recibirán la nueva rama la próxima vez que hagan:

```
git fetch
```

Más info:

- https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Comment: gracias por la respuesta ordago, una duda nada mas, si estoy en la rama master y ejecuto el comando git flow init me creara la rama develop de igual manera sin afectar al repositorio?

Comment: para que quieres ejecutar `git flow init` si ya tienes el repositorio inicializado?

Comment: "When using the git-flow extension library, executing git flow init on an existing repo will create the develop branch." https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow -> Traducido, cuando se usa la librería git-flow, ejecutar git flow init en un repositorio existente creará la rama develop. Por lo que sí, si la creará en local, pero no afectará el repositorio remoto hasta que hagas push.

Comment: supongo que los cambios que se ejecuten al hacer push no romperán mi sitio web, simplemente publicara la rama develop al repositorio remoto es correcto ¿no?

Comment: SI haces push a tu repositorio de bitbucket no afectará a otros repositorios, hasta que hagan fetch o pull.

Comment: @JavierPech te recomiendo que crees preguntas nuevas para estas dudas que te van surgiendo, son interesantes de por si, por lo que podrías tener más oportunidades de respuestas variadas que se pueden estar escapando por realizar la pregunta en el hilo de comentarios.